# How to safely remove exterior metal panel?

Tags: exterior, siding

Under our breakfast nook there is a metal panel like a soffitt or similar. I'd like to remove it so that I can check for insulation inside. However I don't see how to remove this panel without damaging it. I don't see any visible screws or nails on the panel. The panels are a bit flexible. What is the proper way to take this off?

[image: metal panel]
[image: metal panel from side]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is standard aluminum soffit, much like the vinyl sort, and one piece locks into the preceding one the same way. Look closely at both ends, and if you can't see any fasteners try to slide the end piece toward the middle. If it doesn't go try the same on the other end. One end or the other should pop out and you'll then see how it's fastened. It's usually nailed like vinyl. Be careful handling it as it bends and dents easily.

Phil

Comment: Although this didn't exactly work, I was able to see how they were fastened together, but I couldn't get them to unhook from each other even with some force. I ended up having to gently bend the edging back to remove the panel.